# Using ASP.NET Web-Api to login in multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, it's been under development for over an year.

We are going to start other projects using ASP.NET MVC, Xamarin and ASP.NET Web api. Right now, I want to be able to reuse views and controllers so that in the future we don't need to write multiple views/controllers for the same purpose.

I'm currently studying Web api and Xamarin to start the new cross-platform project and my focus is to use my ASP.NET MVC login/registration in this new project.

I've seen a few questions regarding the use of Web api to authenticate users but they do not address the reuse of views/controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the MVC packages to an API project and then create the MVC controllers and views you want to reuse inside of the API, redirecting to those pages on the API as needed.  This would be fine for login stuff, assuming your api project has all of the login functionality.

This would make your API project both a Web API project and an MVC project, though likely with very limited MVC in-use.  This is how the Microsoft Help Pages works if you use that instead of something like Swagger for API documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you point me to any examples of Web api that has login functionality? Or is it just a matter of taking the structure I have in my current project and adapting to the api?